# Allow non-admin user to start program without UAC prompt

Tags: windows, windows-11, uac

Consider my son, who I would prefer to not be configured as an administrator on his computer (Windows 11). There are some applications I want him to be able to open -- for instance -- Armoury Crate from Asus, or Intel ARC Control. Armoury Crate starts on login and he is prompted for an administrator's pin (me).

I've read that I can bypass this by setting up a scheduled task to start the application, so I did. However, this does not work for Intel ARC Control (a GUI application). Also, it's a really bad hack to use the Task Scheduler for this, even if it worked.

There must be a better way ... right?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot allow a standard user to bypass the UAC prompt. Not at all possible for a native Windows system.

If a scheduled task does not work for you (it cannot work for everyone), then you will need to enable the program for your son and train him until you and he can agree upon him being an admin.

Many ordinary programs start as standard user, so this should not be too hard for you.

You should be able to set the properties for a startup task to start with Administrator properties and enter the Admin credentials once.

Natively, there really is no third way.

Comment: This is a GUI application, not a service, etc. Forgot to make that clear.

Comment: Go to the GUI App properties, Shortcut, Advanced and you can start as Admin. I checked several Apps.  When you do this (and save) you will be asked for your Admin credentials.  This should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

A scheduled task will not work, since it cannot interact with your son's
desktop. This is a security feature that basically nixed using a
scheduled task for this purpose.

There exist third-party products that allow a non-administrator
to run some specific commands as administrator without him knowing
the administrator's password.

Here are some such products (without recommendation) :

- [AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) (freeware)
- [Make Me Admin](https://github.com/pseymour/MakeMeAdmin/wiki/) (freeware)
- [RunAsTool](https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-4/) (freeware)
- [RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html) (commercial)
- [Runasrob](https://runasrob.com/) (commercial).
  The free version has an annoying popup window which appears randomly.

Comment: Thank you, will check those out.